# How can I turn on "show open windows" dock element?

Tags: plank

How can I turn on "show open windows" dock element? I deleted this probably accidentally.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Applications menu, right-click on Multitasking View -> Add to Dock.

If by any chance it's not there, create a file called gala-multitaskingview.desktop in /usr/share/applications/ with these contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Multitasking View
Comment=View all open windows and workspaces
GenericName=Multitasking View
Icon=multitasking-view
Terminal=false
Categories=GNOME;GTK;System;
Exec=dbus-send --session --dest=org.pantheon.gala --print-reply /org/pantheon/gala org.pantheon.gala.PerformAction int32:1
X-AppStream-Ignore=true
```

Careful with that Exec line, make sure to copy all of it, it's quite long.

[image: Multitasking View in Slingshot]

EDIT: Just remembered you could also assign the same functionality to one of the corners of your screen. Just go to System Settings -> Desktop -> Hot Corners, pick a corner and select an option from the drop-down menus. 
There is also a keyboard shortcut: `WinKey + A` or `⌘+A`

Answer (score 3):

- Go to the applications bar
- Set your applications bar to "view as grid" by clicking on the icon of four squares on the top left.
- Look for "Multitasking View"
- You should now see the blue icon
- Right click on the icon and choose "Add to Dock"